# Kentor.AuthServices specifying signing certificate in SPSSODescriptor

Tags: authentication, saml, shibboleth, kentor-authservices

I am using Kentor.AuthServices for OWIN.
The IdP I need to federate with requires authentication requests to be signed by the SP.

Therefore, the SP metadata (SPSSODescriptor) must contain a KeyDescriptor use="signing" along with a certificate.

Is this possible using Kentor.AuthServices? If yes, could I get a little guidance on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As of version 0.15.1 this is now supported**

*Original answer:*

No, this is not yet possible, since the AuthServices [metadata element](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/blob/master/doc/Configuration.md#metadata-element) does not currently contain a property for specifying the certificate with which to sign requests (or to encrypt inbound assertions).

However, some related development has been under way, e.g. this pull request of mine which adds the certificate configuration:
https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/pull/273

And this closed pull request which will (hopefully) come back once the above is merged:
https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/blob/master/doc/Configuration.md#metadata-element

Comment: I rebuilt Kentor.Authservices including your commits from #273 and successfully utilized Certificate signing. It worked first go. Thanks very much!! Hopefully it will be making itself into the master branch and the Nuget package soon.